# SCP to create security groups in member AWS account

Tags: network, ssh, tcp, aws

I'm trying to create a SCP to restrict member account users to create/modify security group(s) that have inbound rule for SSH/RDP with Source set as `0.0.0.0` or `::/0`.

Basically, I want users to SSH into EC2 instances only using bastion hosts and not any other machines.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is possible at all but it seems like it should be possible. So far, I've managed to create below policy but stuck at Condition. I've searched AWS docs and policy generator to find fields like `source` but only found `aws:SourceIP` which is the actual IP address of TCP connection and not the `source` in security group inbound rule.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Require_Restricted_SSH_RDP_Inboud_Rule_SG",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
          "arn:awd:ec2:*:*:security-group-rule/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
          "??": {
            "??": "??"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do this with an SCP. SCP is a preventative control, and it's great for most use-cases, and utilizes IAM to execute.

If you look at the IAM documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html), you can see that the `ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress` action doesn't have any conditions that would allow you to specify the ip addresses in the inbound/outbound rules.

Hence SCP can't be used to achieve limiting the CIDR ranges of your security group rules.

You can however, you something like firewall manager to address this, and this is particularly useful if you are in a Organization account. [This post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-continuously-audit-and-limit-security-groups-with-aws-firewall-manager/) has more info.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!. I did actually explored Firewall manager but I'm in a situation where we do not have any critical services but just some member accounts and I was wondering if the cost is really worth.